# What exactly does parallel fork join parallel?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement fork join Verilog code, but something is wrong:

```
reg [7:0] a, b;
initial fork
a = 0;    // initial
b = 0;    // initial
#1 a = 1;  
#1 b = a + 1;  // is b 1 or 2?
join
```

The above code is confusing because `b` is a very vague value.
As I know, the fork join is working as parallel, so I think that `b` should be 1. Am I right?

My simulation result is that the 'b'is 2 not 1. But, in my think, is should be 1. Because the a does not yet 1 at a moment.

I'd trying to make some example code like this.

```
Initial
$display("initial time = %d", $time);

Fork
#1000 $display("spend time = %d at #1000", $time);
#5 $display("spend time = %d at #5", $time);
#50 $display("spend time = %d at #50", $time);
join

$display("main process time = %d", $time);
end
```

then I got this like following.
initial time 0
spend time 5
spend time 50
spend time 1000
main process time 1000

so from this experiment,  I got it about fork join.

So I trying one more like this.

```
Initial begin
'Ifdef FK
fork
'endif
$display ("initial time %d , $time);
a<=0;
b<=0;

#100 a<=1;
#100 b<=a+1;
 'Ifdef FK
join
'Endif
$display ("the output a,b %d %d time %d, a,b, $time);
End
```

The result are like this
    0, 0, 100
Also when off FK
 1, 0, 200
 But I don't understand  above result. Why does they have 0,0,100 and 1,0,200?

Comment: What do you get when you simulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place code in a fork join it is all executed in parallel. I can not see it explicitly mentioned in the [LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) but my understanding is that for parallel blocks the order of execution is not deterministic. Therefore you would not know if the simulator was going to execute `#1 a = 1;` or `#1 b = a + 1;` first.

Section 9.3.2 of [SystemVerilog IEEE1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) covers parallel blocks.

When you have code in `initial` the code is executed sequentially by the simulator evaluating each line in turn, this is deterministic, code executed in the order written.

An equivalent of your fork join would be:

```
initial 
  a = 0;    

initial 
  b = 0;    

initial 
  #1 a = 1;  

initial
  #1 b = a + 1;
```